# Clear buffers before calling YYACCEPT in yacc/lex

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex, lexer

Is there any way to clear parser buffers before calling `YYACCEPT` in `yacc`.

If i do not clear buffer it causes some problems when i call `yyparse` for the second time.

Also note that I am using some global variables, so cannot use reentrant parser.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is. See [this section](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Multiple-Input-Buffers) of the flex manual. Specifically, call `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER` before calling `yyparse`.

Comment: can you tell me how to exactly use this function `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER`??

Comment: @nav_jan in your code somewhere, you have a line with `yyparse();` so just before this line put `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER();` and you should be good.

Comment: do I need to include any special header for this function?

Comment: @nav_jan Sorry, you need `extern YY_FLUSH_BUFFER;` in your prologue section. And, checking one of my projects, it apparently doesn't use `()` at the end. So the call is just `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER;`.

Comment: adding `extern YY_FLUSH_BUFFER;` in the prologue section gives error while compiling are you sure this is how it is used ?

Comment: It worked without adding `extern YY_FLUSH_BUFFER;` and just calling it before calling `fopen()` call in the lexer. Thanks !!